# How to execute a function before reloadGrid in jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, triggers, event-handling, eventtrigger

I want to run a function every time the grid reloads.

So How can I achieve that?

I am invoking reloadGrid by this:

```
jQuery("#myGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");
```

I have a function

```
function myFunc()
{
 // Do something
}
```

I am not getting the reloadGrid event handler. If I get that one, then I can just bind reloadGrid again with the handler call and `myFunc()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solve it by this:

```
$('#myGrid').on('reloadGrid', myFunc());
```

Comment: what kind of actions you want to do in `myFunc`? The solution seems me a little strange. There are many other callbacks and events which are supported by jqGrid. Probably it's better to use there instead of `reloadGrid`?

Comment: There's a separate text box. I want to make that box empty whenever grid reloads.
Actually is there any way to identify if the user is reloading the grid by clicking button or any internal function is reloading the grid?
Although I can identify clicking of the "refresh" button by simply binding an event to that button. But is there any other way?

Comment: It seems that you can just use `loadComplete` callback or `"jqGridLoadComplete"` event. If loading is very slow and you really need to call `myFunc` *before* strarting loading then you can use `beforeRequest` callback or `"jqGridBeforeRequest"` event alternatively. By the way Reloading of grid will be initialized for example on sorting of grid too.